# What's the purpose of programming to an interface?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, superclass

I have surprisingly never understood the purpose of doing this:

```
Map telephoneNumbers = new HashMap();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

instead of doing this:

```
HashMap telephoneNumbers = new HashMap();
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

?

Comment: the title of the question might not be very good, please feel free to edit it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first two sentences abstract the implementation of your collections. I mean, you know you have a Map and a List but you are not chained to an specific implementation.

On the other hand, variables *telephoneNumbers* and *list* are forced to use the concrete implementation: a HashTable and a List in an array.

So if you use your first variable set you are programming to an interface and not to implementation which is a basic OOP principle: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
HashMap telephoneNumbers = new HashMap();
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You are tied to a specific implementation, i.e. `ArrayList`. If you were to pass the `list` object further to other methods, then you are not much flexible. If you program to interface, say `Collection` instead (which is extended by `List`), you can change the implementation later. For example, if the objects in the list should be unique, then you could easily change it to be a `Set` instead (because sets only contain unique objects):

```
HashMap telephoneNumbers = new HashMap();
Collection<Object> list = new HashSet<Object>();
```

The principle of programming to an interface is really about dependency relationships. It is closely related to the concept of [OO concept of Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_science%29):

> - A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components.
> - A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.

The most important aspect is that by following programming-to-an-interface paradigm we are asking ourself "what" the class can do but not "how" it will do it, which is concerned with the actual implementation.

Using `ArrayList` you are tightly coupling your code to the `ArrayList` class. If you only use the generic methods that are in the `Collection` interface (`add()`, `remove()` etc) then it definitely makes sense to declare your `list` as an interface of type `Collection`.

Comment: [An example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22373138/1122039) of the advantage of interfaces - it would not be so easy if JsonObjectBuilder was a class.

Answer (score 1):

One reason -- it makes it easier to swap out implementations.

Suppose you want to use a TreeMap instead of HashMap, so you can print the telephone numbers in order. Or maybe you want to use a LinkedList instead of ArrayList so you can insert/delete/sort more quickly.

If you use the interface version (Map and List), then you would only have to make these changes in one place, where you constructed the data structures.