# How to work around the limitations of javax.json.jsonObjectBuilder

Tags: java, json

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html) says this:

> This class does not allow `null` to be used as a name or value while building the JSON object

To me, that sounds like a showstopper. If I'm processing customer data from a web form, and someone enters their middle name, password, secret question answer, etc. as "null" then I'm not going to be able to construct a Json object with the correct value in it. Is there a way around this? Some way I could encode the name into the JSON builder and then fix it afterwards? I'm reluctant to do regular expressions on the generated JSON code, that's how the code is currently built and it's a complete mess. I'm trying to replace all the regular expression cruft with proper JSON building code.

Please note that I am talking the four-character string "null", N-U-L-L but in lower case, I am not talking about an actual empty or missing or null value.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363925/jsr-353-how-to-add-null-values-using-javax-json-jsonobjectbuilder)?

Comment: That's talking about null values, not values that are the four-character string "null", N-U-L-L but in lower case. These two things are not the same!

Comment: There's any difference on building with reading? are you sure you can't read as well?

Comment: I don't understand your question - I'm not trying to read anything, I'm trying to create JSON that looks like `{ "value": "null" }`

Comment: Just use Gson instead.

Comment: Read the documentation again.  They are not referring to the string value "null", but to the value `null`.